# Mule ESB Instance Monitoring

Tags: mule

what is the best way to monitor the Mule ESB instances. Is there a way i can get alerted when my mule instance goes down for some reason. I have 4 instances of Mule running and how will I come to know if 1 of them got down due to some reason.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are running community edition? (Enterprise edition provides a [Management Console which allows you to define alerts](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Working+With+Alerts)). If you are using CE, then you are able to [enable JMX monitoring](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/JMX+Management) on the instances and then use one of many ways to verify based on JMX info, whether your server is running. One way is to write your own application that [retrieves JMX data programmatically](https://dzone.com/articles/retrieving-jmx-information) and act accordingly.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mule EE, you can use MMC to monitor all your instances as Gabriel has already suggested. My suggestion would be to install MMC inside tomcat on a separate server. This is to ensure that even if your Mule Server crashes or goes down, your MMC is still running and can send you alerts about your Mule server downtime. You can refer below link for details on how to setup server down and up alerts.
https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Working+With+Alerts

Additionally I would recommend to use MMC with database persistence to ensure you have ability to recover MMC workspace even if your MMC server crashes. You can refer about MMC setup with DB persistence at below link.
https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Configuring+MMC+for+External+Databases+-+Quick+Reference

If you don't have Mule EE, you may want to explore other tools or customer alerting applications as suggested by Gabriel.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a JMX agent by adding the following lines into your "conf/wrapper.conf" file :

```
wrapper.java.additional.19=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
wrapper.java.additional.20=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10055
wrapper.java.additional.21=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
wrapper.java.additional.22=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
wrapper.java.additional.23=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
```

don't forget to change the values accordingly. Also you can implement SSL authentication with a few extra lines.

Now once your monitoring platform is set up you can always activate Java pollers and start the server.